# Postfix content_filter bcc

Tags: ruby, bash, email, postfix-mta, dovecot

There is a way to check BCC recipient using content_filter= in postfix master?
The point is I have a script called "tool" which I called from postfix like:

```
flags=Rq user=filter argv=/usr/local/bin/tool -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

And all works fine except in recipient I have all recipients (to, cc and bcc). I just need to do something at my script with those in BCC.

So right now when I print my ARGV I see the list of all of them. I tried to do it using Ruby script and mikel/mail gem, but as I see there is no option to simply check bcc.

How can I pass BCC recipients to my script? Or how can I read them in my script?

Comment: You cannot match on the `Bcc:` header because it is not there when you receive a message. http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#bcc is for Procmail but applies in broad terms here as well.  Not a programming question, anyway; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].